# product duplication Woocommerce / review-order.php / checkout form

Tags: php

I am currently working on a cosmetics shop project
Using WP+ woocommerce for the backend

Well, in the final stage of order processing (checkout)
woocommerce uses a file review-order.php to display the product selected by the user

As I am using a custom theme, I need my blocks to look custom too
Here's what my code looks like

```
<table class="shop_table woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table">
    <?php
/**

 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 5.2.0
 */

defined('ABSPATH') || exit;
?>

<?php
        do_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_cart_contents');

        foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
            $_product = apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key);

            if ($_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters('woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key)) {
                ?>
                <?php
                // Get the product data
                $product = $cart_item['data'];
                $product_id = $product->get_id();
                $product_name = $product->get_name();
                $product_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($product_id), 'thumbnail');
                $product_price = $product->get_price();
                $product_quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
                // Calculate total price
                $total_price = $product_price * $product_quantity;
                ?>

                <div class="productItem">
                    <div class="productItem__body">
                        <div class="productItem__picture">
                            <img src="<?php echo $product_image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product_name; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="productItem__description">
                            <h5 class="productItem__name">
                                <?php echo $product_name; ?>
                            </h5>
                            <div class="productItem__price">
                                <div class="pricePP">
                                    <div class="nonDiscountPrice">
                                        123123
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="actualPrice">
                                        <?php echo wc_price($product_price); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <p class="product-quantity">
                                <?php echo __('', 'your-text-domain') . ' ' . $product_quantity; ?>
                            </p>
                            <div>
                                <?php echo wc_price($total_price); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <?php
            }
        }
        
        ?>
        
        
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="product-name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th class="product-total"><?php esc_html_e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_cart_contents' );

        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $_product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

            if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                ?>
                <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">
                    <td class="product-name">
                        <?php echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) . '&nbsp;'; ?>
                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( '&times;&nbsp;%s', $cart_item['quantity'] ) . '</strong>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                        <?php echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="product-total">
                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }

        do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents' );
        ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>

        <tr class="cart-subtotal">
            <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <td><?php wc_cart_totals_subtotal_html(); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons() as $code => $coupon ) : ?>
            <tr class="cart-discount coupon-<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $code ) ); ?>">
                <th><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_label( $coupon ); ?></th>
                <td><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_html( $coupon ); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php if ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && WC()->cart->show_shipping() ) : ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping' ); ?>

            <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_fees() as $fee ) : ?>
            <tr class="fee">
                <th><?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?></th>
                <td><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php if ( wc_tax_enabled() && ! WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) : ?>
            <?php if ( 'itemized' === get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_total_display' ) ) : ?>
                <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_tax_totals() as $code => $tax ) : // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited ?>
                    <tr class="tax-rate tax-rate-<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $code ) ); ?>">
                        <th><?php echo esc_html( $tax->label ); ?></th>
                        <td><?php echo wp_kses_post( $tax->formatted_amount ); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <tr class="tax-total">
                    <th><?php echo esc_html( WC()->countries->tax_or_vat() ); ?></th>
                    <td><?php wc_cart_totals_taxes_total_html(); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total' ); ?>

        <tr class="order-total">
            <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <td><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total' ); ?>

    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Using this code - my products on the page are duplicated, but the price remains correct!
for example
user selected 1 shampoo for $10 and 1 hand cream for $8
Displayed a total of 4 blocks of goods (2 shampoo and 2 cream )
but the amount is still correct (18$)

Please help me, colleagues

i`ve tried to left just markup like :

```
<?php
// Loop through each cart item
foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
    $_product = apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key);

    if ($_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters('woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key)) {
        // Get the product data
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $product_id = $product->get_id();
        $product_name = $product->get_name();
        $product_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($product_id), 'thumbnail');
        $product_price = $product->get_price();
        $product_quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
        // Calculate total price
        $total_price = $product_price * $product_quantity;
        ?>

        <div class="productItem">
            <div class="productItem__body">
                <div class="productItem__picture">
                    <img src="<?php echo $product_image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product_name; ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="productItem__description">
                    <h5 class="productItem__name">
                        <?php echo $product_name; ?>
                    </h5>
                    <div class="productItem__price">
                        <div class="pricePP">
                            <div class="nonDiscountPrice">
                                123123
                            </div>
                            <div class="actualPrice">
                                <?php echo wc_price($product_price); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="product-quantity">
                        <?php echo __('', 'your-text-domain') . ' ' . $product_quantity; ?>
                    </p>
                    <div>
                        <?php echo wc_price($total_price); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

had the right amount of goods
But in this case my delivery didn't work.

To use it, I had to add

```
<?php if (WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && WC()->cart->show_shipping()) : ?>

            <?php do_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping'); ?>

            <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>

            <?php do_action('woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping'); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

but delivery in this case also not working , because u need to keep the  tag with required classes

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.